# Simple PHP Table Total

Tags: php, sum

I've been trying for ages to simply calculate the "weight" field we have added to an invoice plugin called sliced invoices. All I need is for it to total the weight based on the value in the table.

The weight field has the div class, "adjust". Here's a link to the forms PDF and you'll see the empty table field - Weight. http://cavcon.co.za/sliced_quote/346-2/?create=pdf&id=346&print_pdf=8d39bfe988

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
         <?php
            $count = 0;
            $items = sliced_get_invoice_line_items(); // gets quote and invoice
            if( !empty( $items ) ) :

                foreach ( $items[0] as $item ) {

                    $class = ($count % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
                    $item_tax = isset( $item['tax'] ) ? $item['tax'] : 0;
                    $line_total = $shared->get_line_item_sub_total( $item['qty'], $item['amount']); 
                    ?>

                        <tr class="row_<?php echo $class; ?> sliced-item">

                            <td class="qty"><?php echo esc_html( $item['qty'] ); ?></td>
                            <td class="service"><?php echo esc_html( isset( $item['title'] ) ? $item['title'] : '' ); ?>
                                <?php if ( isset( $item['description'] ) ) : ?>
                                    <br/><span class="description"><?php echo esc_html( $item['description']); ?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="rate"><?php echo esc_html( $shared->get_formatted_currency( $item['amount'] ) ); ?></td>
                            <?php if ( sliced_hide_adjust_field() === false) { ?>
                                <td class="adjust"><?php echo esc_html( $item_tax ? $item['tax'] . 'kg' : '-' ); ?></td>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( $shared->get_formatted_currency( $line_total ) ); ?></td>

                        </tr>

                <?php $count++; 
                } 
            endif; ?>

            </tbody>

        </table> 

    <?php
 }

   endif;



 if ( ! function_exists( 'sliced_display_invoice_totals' ) ) :

function sliced_display_invoice_totals() { ?>

        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="new-table">

            <tbody>
                <?php do_action( 'sliced_invoice_before_totals' ); ?>
                <tr class="row-sub-total">
                    <td class="rate"><?php echo _e( 'Total Weight', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="total-weight"><?php echo esc_html( $item['weight'] ); ?>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row-sub-total">
                    <td class="rate"><?php echo _e( 'Sub Total', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_sub_total() ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row-tax">
                    <td class="rate"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_tax_name() ); ?></td>
                    <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_tax() ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-active row-total">
                    <td class="rate"><strong><?php echo _e( 'Total', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></strong></td>
                    <td class="total"><strong><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_total() ); ?></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php do_action( 'sliced_invoice_after_totals' ); ?>
            </tbody>

        </table>


    <?php
}

endif;
```

THIS IS WHERE I'M AT

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sliced_display_invoice_totals' ) ) :

$total_weight = 0;
foreach ( $items[0] as $item ) {
  $total_weight = $total_weight + $item['tax'];

 }

function sliced_display_invoice_totals() { ?>  

        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="new-table">

            <tbody>
                <?php do_action( 'sliced_invoice_before_totals' ); ?>

                <tr class="row-sub-total">
                    <td class="rate"><?php echo _e( 'Total Weight', 'sliced-          
       invoices' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="total-weight"><?php echo esc_html(  
       $total_weight . 'kg') ?>



                 </td>
```

Comment: In *sliced_display_invoice_totals()* you refer to *$item['weight']*, but *$item* is not defined in that function.

Comment: You say *weight field has the div class, "adjust".*, but the only place where I see that class in your code, is where you output the tax. This doesn't add up.

Comment: In your code, the weight seem to be `$item[tax]` (???).  If it is correct, you can calc total by `array_sum(array_column($items,'tax'))` (on PHP >= 5.5)... but really weight reside in `$item[tax]`?

Comment: That's correct. The weight is $item[tax]. We changed the field names to suit what we were trying to achieve. How do I output the array sum total?

Comment: I tried this with no such luck: <?php
array_sum(array_column($item,'tax'));
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($item,'tax') . "\n";
?>

Comment: Hey @fusion3k could you please assist. :)

Comment: @trincot - please assist too if possible. I think we're nearly there!

Comment: @Ben you have to pay attention when coding. If something wrong double-check it, compare it with example, try to understand the logic. Please read careful my prev comments and compare it with last your comment

Comment: @fusion3k I have tried your approach with no luck mate. I need to echo the sum value. I used this: array_sum(array_column($item['tax'])); and i tried this array_sum(array_column($items['tax']));

Comment: first of all, you have correct php version (see my comment: 5.5 or above)? Then: none of your three posted codes is the same as mine.

Comment: @fusion3k - we are currently using php version 5.6. I tried your original approach, array_sum(array_column($items,'tax')) with no such luck. How would I output that value?

Comment: `echo array_sum ...; ` or `$something = array_sum ....; echo $something;`

Comment: <?php
array_sum(array_column($item,'tax'));
echo array_sum($item,'tax')
?>

Comment: Not working.. Doesn't seem to be pulling any values from $item tax

Comment: If you look at the weight column I now have a value displayed. Making progress! It doesn't sum the value though as I assume it's only picking up 1 value per column. http://cavcon.co.za/sliced_quote/346-2/?create=pdf&id=346&print_pdf=8d39bfe988

Comment: @fusion3k - this is the code I used to get something to display. <?php
$a = array($item['tax']);
echo array_sum($a) . "\n";

?>

Comment: @fusion3k - it just doesn't sum the columns though..

Comment: @Ben, it would be helpful if you could include example output of `var_export ($items);` right after you get that array from `sliced_get_invoice_line_items()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run PHP version 5.5 or above, you can sum the weights in this way:

```
if( !empty( $items ) ) :
    foreach ( $items[0] as $item ) {
        (...)
    }
    $total_weight = array_sum( array_column( $items, 'tax' ) );
endif; ?>
```

Otherwise, you have to increment `$total_weight` inside `foreach` loop:

```
$total_weight = 0;
foreach ( $items[0] as $item ) {
    $total_weight = $total_weight + $item['tax'];
    (...)
}
```

If you output total weight in the same [`scope`](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php) of above script, simply put `echo $total_weight;` where you want to print it (or `echo esc_html( $total_weight . 'kg');`, according with your other prints).

But maybe your totals is output through `sliced_display_invoice_totals` function (although I don't see any call to this function in your code); in this case, the `$total_weight` variable is not directly available in the function, due to different [`scope`](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php). You have to print it in this way:

```
function sliced_display_invoice_totals() { ?>
    (...)

    echo $GLOBALS['total_weight'];  // or echo esc_html( $GLOBALS['total_weight'] . 'kg');
    (...)
}
```

#### Pleae careful note:

In your code, the function `sliced_display_invoice_totals` declaration is prepended by condition `if ( ! function_exists( 'sliced_display_invoice_totals' ) )`: this means that, if the function is already defined, your function modification **will be ignored**: in this case, you have to modify the already declare function instead.

To see if the function is already declared, place this temporary code before `if` condition:

```
if( function_exists( 'sliced_display_invoice_totals' ) )
{
    $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction( 'sliced_display_invoice_totals' );
    die( $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine() );
}
```

In this way you can see the filePath and line in which the function is defined and modify it.

---

- See more about [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- See more about [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- See more about [Variables scope](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php)
- See more about [Reflection class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php)

Comment: Thanks so much for such an informative response mate. I'm going to try all the methods outlined until one works. I just need to know what to input for (...) ?

Comment: just tagging you to notify you of my comment above.

Comment: please see my original post above and look for "THIS IS WHERE I'M AT". I'm not too sure if I'm doing the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of things to change:

#### 1. Unpaired HTML tags

The code in your question does not include the `<table>` nor `<tbody>` tags which you later close. I assume they are present in your original code.

#### 2. Unpaired braces

Maybe also just an error while drafting your question, but after the `</table>` there is a closing PHP `}` and `endif` which have no matching opening statements.

#### 3. Use of `_e`

According to the [documentation of `_e()` on wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e):

> Displays the returned translated text from `translate()`
>   [...]
>   This function does not return a value.

So you are not supposed to write `echo _e(...)`, you should just write `_e(...)` instead.

#### 4. Function *sliced_display_invoice_totals*

You define this function that displays the totals, but you never call it. If you intend to display that table then do just that, without function definition.

#### 5. When *$items* is empty

You have a condition so that the first table is only produced when *$items* is not empty. However, the totals table is produced outside that context, so it would also be produced when *$items* is empty. This might not be what you want. Consider moving the code for the second table inside that `if` block.

#### 6. Mixed use of normal and alternative syntax

You use often the `:` ... `endif` syntax, which can indeed be helpful to read code that is interrupted by HTML code. But you don't use it consistently. I suggest using it for all `if` statements and for the `foreach` construct as well.

#### 7. Calculate and display the *$total_weight*

Inside your existing `foreach` loop, add the weight of each line to *$total_weight*. You must also initialise this value just before starting the loop with 0.

Then in the second table display that *$total_weight* with the same format as you display the individual weights in the first table.

Here is the code that has all of the above applied:

```php
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="detail-table">
    <tbody>
<?php
$count = 0;
$items = sliced_get_invoice_line_items(); // gets quote and invoice
// *** add this line ***
$total_weight = 0;
if( !empty( $items ) ) :
    foreach ( $items[0] as $item ) :
        $class = ($count % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
        $item_tax = isset( $item['tax'] ) ? $item['tax'] : 0;
        // *** add this line ***
        $total_weight += $item_tax;
        $line_total = $shared->get_line_item_sub_total( $item['qty'], $item['amount']); 
?>
        <tr class="row_<?php echo $class; ?> sliced-item">
            <td class="qty"><?php echo esc_html( $item['qty'] ); ?></td>
            <td class="service"><?php echo esc_html( isset( $item['title'] ) ? $item['title'] : '' ); ?>
<?php   if ( isset( $item['description'] ) ) : 
?>          <br/><span class="description"><?php echo esc_html( $item['description']); ?></span>
<?php   endif;
?>          </td>
            <td class="rate"><?php echo esc_html( $shared->get_formatted_currency( $item['amount'] ) ); ?></td>
<?php   if ( sliced_hide_adjust_field() === false) :
?>          <td class="adjust"><?php echo esc_html( $item_tax ? $item['tax'] . 'kg' : '-' ); ?></td>
<?php   endif;
?>
            <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( $shared->get_formatted_currency( $line_total ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php $count++; 
    endforeach; // use consistent syntax (alternative)
?>
    </tbody>
</table> 

<?php
// **** Remove the IF and the FUNCTION. You want to execute this now. ***
?>

<table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="new-table">
    <tbody>
        <?php do_action( 'sliced_invoice_before_totals' ); ?>
        <tr class="row-sub-total">
            <td class="rate"><?php _e( 'Total Weight', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></td>
            <td class="total-weight"><?php echo esc_html( $total_weight ? $total_weight . 'kg' : '-' ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-sub-total">
            <td class="rate"><?php _e( 'Sub Total', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></td>
            <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_sub_total() ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-tax">
            <td class="rate"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_tax_name() ); ?></td>
            <td class="total"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_tax() ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-active row-total">
            <td class="rate"><strong><?php _e( 'Total', 'sliced-invoices' ); ?></strong></td>
            <td class="total"><strong><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_total() ); ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php do_action( 'sliced_invoice_after_totals' ); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
// **** Consider closing the if (!empty($items)) here ***
endif;
?>
```

You did not specify the code for the many functions you call, like *sliced_get_tax_name*, *sliced_get_invoice_tax*,... etc. Unless there is a problem with any of these functions, the above code should work.